# Copy rows and insert in source table

Tags: mysql, copy

In MySQL I have a table design like this:

```
Language|Key|Text
```

Language and Key are primary keys. A content example could be:

```
("ENU","P_Home_H2","Welcome to my page"),
("ENU","P_Home_P1","Hello world!")
```

Now I want to copy all rows with Language="ENU" to Language="ESP", ie select all rows where Language = "ENU" and insert into same table, with same Key and Text but Language="ESP". The result would be:

```
("ESP","P_Home_H2","Welcome to my page"),
("ESP","P_Home_P1","Hello world!")
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Do you mean (language,key) is a primary key? Otherwise it would not work, primary keys have to be unique and you can just have one per table.

Comment: Yes I know - Language and Key are primary key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Insert into MyTable
Select 'ESP' as Language, Key, Text
From MyTable 
Where Language = 'ENU'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO existingTable
Select 'ESP' as Language, [Key], Text
FROM newTable
WHERE Language = 'ENU'
```